# Is my Flask session cookie secure? Same csrf_token on all pages/views and forms

Tags: security, flask, session-cookies, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm in the final state of my first Flask app and i'm trying to make sure that it has the security necessary to protect the users and their information. It's a simple platform where users can register/login/logout and make posts. I'm using Flask-Login for logging in the users and storing the data (username, email, password) in a SQL database using SQLAlchemy and for the forms i'm using Flask-WTF. The thing is, yesterday i found out about how Flask handles session cookies and that they're signed but not encrypted, so they shouldn't contain any secret information and here's my concern: When decoding and analyzing the session cookie in various scenarios, i found some information that i'm not sure if should be there or not.

For example, when logged in, the cookie stores the user's id which is the id of the user in the database. Though I read on an article and video from [Miguel Grinberg(see comment #11)](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-secure-is-the-flask-user-session)  about it and now i know that having the user's id on the cookie may not be an issue, **i don't know how that id got in there, because i didn't write any code to put it in the session or anything.**

Another thing that i see stored in the cookie when i access the login route, login and then logout, there is now another element in the cookie which is the **csrf_token (i'm using flask-wtf to make the forms and making use of the form.hidden_tag() ).** It first appears in the cookie when i access the login route/form, and it stays in the cookie all the time the user is logged in, and even when logged out, the cookie still has that element. I don't know if it's OK to have the csrf token on the cookie, and if it's not, **I don't know how to not include it either**, because as I said with the user Id, **i didn't write any code to include the csrf_token in the cookie, so i don't really know what is including it there.**

To illustrate you better, here is the content of the cookie in the various scenarios i talk about:

NOTE: **the IP Address is included by me, which is the only element i explicitly wrote code to include in the session**. Not the cookie but the session.

```
when accesing the website @ localhost:5000, session cookie contains this information:
{
    "_fresh": false,
    "user_ip": "127.0.0.1"
}


then, when accesing login route, session cookie contains now this information (should this csrf_token be here?):
{
    "_fresh": false,
    "csrf_token": "10106b35c897dfd877367f68a8924761239c7ddd",
    "user_ip": "127.0.0.1"
}

then, when loggin in, session cookie now contains this information:
{
    "_fresh": true,
    "_id": "a1a2a05700b69fb7a02745a1c87d131168cc1d5a0173e222e402bd334d9e1b6
            a9fa2ac7bfbfe325e7b04eb9b852f5a39e396eab8a2c333ecff36c698f80f9de8",
    "_user_id": "1", #this is the user id in the database
    "csrf_token": "10106b35c897dfd877367f68a8924761239c7ddd",
    "user_ip": "127.0.0.1"
}

then, when logged out, session cookie contains this information:
{
    "_fresh": false,
    "csrf_token": "10106b35c897dfd877367f68a8924761239c7ddd",
    "user_ip": "127.0.0.1"
}
```

I know now that having the user_id in the cookie may not be an issue (thought i'm thinking on replacing it for maybe the user's username) but what is bugging me is that through all the views/pages and forms in the website, **the csrf_token is the same in the cookie** even if the view doesn't contain a form, and i don't know if it should be there.

If you can help me with any tips or any information about if this is an issue and how can i resolve, and how could i improve the security of the website i would really appreciate it. If you have any questions or don't really understand what i'm talking about in this post, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how flask-wtf implements CSRF controls [here](https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/blob/main/src/flask_wtf/csrf.py). Basically, flask-wtf will add the csrf token to your session (and therefore in the cookie) and compare the value to your submitted forms value.

There is no risk in providing the CSRF token in the cookie. Many frameworks do exactly the same, have a CSRF token stored in cookies (many times as a seprate cookie) and add it in any forms. After the submission of a form, the two values will be compared to check if the request was not "forged".

An attacker who acquires the whole cookie, has nothing to gain from using the CSRF token, as they can already takeover the victim's account.

You can read more on [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) about CSRF and this kind of protection. This protection is not secure only when you do not fully control all the subdomains of your website, as you will see in the provided link.